# Is it OK to call Facade for internal use?

Tags: java, design-patterns, facade

I have recently seen an EJB code with a **Facade** pattern to provide some methods to be used in presentation layer (JSF). But in some part of the business logic, the methods of the Facade is called and have been used.

That seems a little strange to me since I think the Facade is supposed to serve the outer world not the internal functionality. Am I right or I got paranoid?

This is a rough (*stupid*) diagram to illustrate the situation:

[image: Facade's wanna-be]

Comment: I think you are right. If the function should be used from business logic than it should just delagate that to some other entity.

Comment: In GoF term, internal classes don't know anything about Facade. If internal classes use Facade, then it becomes Mediator.

Comment: @nikita, thanks. That was a good one.

Comment: @nikita Incorrect - a facade is defined as "Provide a unified interface to a set of interfaces in a subsystem." in the original GoF sense. It has no restrictions on internal or external, a facade is completely different implementation wise from a mediator.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary no. Proof - https://books.google.ru/books/content?id=6oHuKQe3TjQC&hl=ru&pg=PT203&img=1&zoom=3&bul=1&sig=ACfU3U2N99VdPvvs1EQfmhsCioi6pljWGg&w=1280. Classic book - "Design Patterns
Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software" publish date 1994 (https://www.google.ru/books/edition/Design_Patterns/6oHuKQe3TjQC?hl=ru&gbpv=1&dq=Elements+of+Reusable+Object-Oriented+Software&printsec=frontcover). Also on mediator- https://books.google.ru/books/content?id=6oHuKQe3TjQC&hl=ru&pg=PT290&img=1&zoom=3&bul=1&sig=ACfU3U0Bj6WRbBdWwVUIU9RWbnYvekWoHw&w=1280

Comment: No - the mediator is for when you want multiple objects to have a "mediator" between them. A facade is used to simplify & unifying the interface for interacting with a set of more complex classes that belong to some subsystem whether internal or external. They do 2 completely different jobs.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary I don't remember saying that they are same. My point was that `mediator` is used when all components talk to each other through it - so they know about mediator. In `facade` inner components don't know about facade. Of course they are different just because of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you shouldn't in my opinion. The façade is there to regulate the interface between layers; it shouldn't be used from inside the layer as well.

And it shouldn't be necessary either. I'm assuming `getProductById` delegates the call to some sort of repository which fetches the `Product`. You can use dependency injection to inject your repository in the appropriate classes. In the small UML sample I drew up just now (it's been a while, forgive me if some connections aren't correct) I demonstrate this approach.

[image]

Now the `Report` class has access to the `ProductRepository` and can fetch the data from there instead of going through the Façade class.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you are right! Facade provides an interface of something complex, by hiding the complexity and haphazardness to its client. The client can be `JSF` view page, another bean or service. There is no technical problem as long as you are using it accordingly!

But generally, if you have done layering in conventional manners, it should not be like what you described.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. Although I accepted Jeroen's answer but I'll give you some up-votes instead since your answer was as good as his.

Comment: Additional Facades class can be created to prevent that a single facade has many responsibilities.
This can avoid unrelated features come together in a single complex structure. Becose of this I think that facades can be used by both clients and other facades.